# Plupload - Show a warning when using Flash Runtime and the Browser has no Flash

Tags: javascript, plupload

I need to show an info message when Plupload decides to use Flash but the Browser doesn't support it.

Currently nothing happens(TM) after plupload.init() and even though the API specifies a "runtime"-property which should name the used runtime I could find no way to find the currently used runtime.

This results in a non-working Upload-Button and the user does not understand whats going on.

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
if(plupload.runtime == "flash" && !detect_flash()) {
    $("#flash_warning").show();
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you having this issue. What browser is it? If it cannot load flash for whatever reason.. it will not load it and fall back to your next defined selection.. or usually html4 standard post.

Comment: I disabled html4 because I rely on chunked uploads. The uploaded files range from 15MB up to 2GB. This only happens when the user uses Internet Explorer, has no Flash and no Silverlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, failed runtime loading attempts do not seem to trigger any event you can subscribe to.
So I don't see any way to subscribe to a failed runtime loading attempt aside from modifying plupload sources.

Open plupload.js or pluploadfull.js, look for the first match of '.init('. 
What you want to subscribe to is the 'else' part of the callback function that processes loading attempt (just before calling w() at the end of the following line )

```
G.init(B,function(H){if(H&&H.success){B.features=F;B.runtime=G.name;B.trigger("Init",{runtime:G.name});B.trigger("PostInit");B.refresh()}else{w()}})
```

Anyway, best thing to do in my opinion is to follow the examples and have a disclaimer message in the container which is supposed to hold the uploader. This way, if all runtimes fail to load, you will have your disclaimer message.

Comment: Its not that I want an failed init event, I just want to know which runtime Plupload decided to use. Patching the source is an obvious workaround, but I had hoped that there is some functionality I just couldn't find ;) Anyways, I'll check out the idea with the disclaimer message inside the container. Thanks!

Comment: When you write "decides to use Flash", I understand that Init triggers for the flash runtime (so plupload checked the browser supports it) 

When flash is disabled or not installed on the browser, Init does not trigger for the flash runtime. That was my answer : catching a failed attempt to use flash.

Could you describe a situation where plupload decides to use flash (Init triggers) but flash is not available. I am currently integrating plupload, that would help me.

Interesting thing I'd like to achieve also : http://www.plupload.com/example_custom.php offers to download flash if not enabled

Comment: Yeah, that line was a little confusing... the init function was simply not triggered - I have yet to encounter a situation where a runtime was detected but could not be loaded, but in this case I'd talk the the company behind Plupload because thats an obvious bug.

Comment: I simply decided to show an info box along the lines of this: "Upload initializing.. if this message does not disappear, something is wrong" (veeery short version of it) and just call $("#msg").hide() in the init callback.